# Custom ribbon/banner instead of MsgBox

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I have a program that detects an attachment's filesize and displays a `MsgBox` if it's larger than a predefined size.

My question is, instead of using a `MsgBox`, is it possible to use a custom inline ribbon or banner?  Below is an image of an example I'd like to reproduce.  Specifically, I'd like to recreate the pink banner above the email body instead of popping up a `MsgBox` if and only if the filesize meets the size criteria, otherwise it looks completely normal.

http://gaspull.geeksaresexytech.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/03/outlook1.jpg

Can anyone point me to a source or reference to do more homework?  I've searched Google, but I don't think I'm searching the correct keywords, because my searches keep coming up with other stuff.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko's suggestion below looks interesting, but perhaps is overkill. You may considering some VBA to manipulate the email's `.HTMLBody` and then the `Application_ItemSend` event to either remove that portion of the HTML, or cancel the `ItemSend`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest modifying your code to insert some HTML to the `MailItem.HTMLBody`.

Depending on your skill with HTML (it is not really my forte...) you could probably come very close to matching the look & feel of that notification.

Then, you can use the `ItemSend` event to figure out what to do with the email.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Select Case TypeName(Item)
    Case "MailItem"

        If InStr(1, Item.HTMLBody, GetWarningMessage) Then
            'If you want to cancel the send, then do this:
            Cancel = True
            MsgBox "Attachment is too big to send!"

            'Or, if you want to send anyways, do this:
            'Item.HTMLBody = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, GetWarningMessage, vbNullString)

        End If
    Case Else
    'Do nothing, or modify as needed
End Select

End Sub
```

You will need to modify this function to return the correct substring representing your warning message.  I used simple text highlighting/etc. but you could use shapes, or smart art, etc., I think.

```
Function GetWarningMessage() As String

Dim str$
str = "<p class=MsoNormal><b><span style='color:red;background:silver;mso-highlight:silver'>Warning:</span></b><span style='color:red;background:silver;mso-highlight:silver'> </span><span style='background:silver;mso-highlight:silver'>This message contains an attachment that is too large to send.</span><o:p></o:p></p>"
GetWarningMessage = str
End Function
```

Comment: David, this looks to be a great solution, but within the environment I'm in, emails default to plain text and as such, this would not work for me, but +1 for a good idea.  Thanks.